# Tree structure based on data from database + faster tree operations

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, tree, gson

I would like to have a 'n' level tree on my website, that is based on the data from database. I have made my mind on my java data structure. But i fear that i might loose some client side performance when trying to render my details from my java data structure (generic tree element with parent,list of children).

Now am validating 2 options:

- Try and render my java data structure using plain JSP tags / Javascript or Ajax
- Prepare a JSON from my data structure and work with JSON on my client side. PLanning to use GSON for serialze and De-serialize,don't know if this is an overhead. Cause i constantly have to refresh my tree based on filters/search etc

Tree operations i need to support are:

1. Traversal - More than one branch could be expanded at a time, my tree(more of a graph) can have the same branch repeating at different levels
2. I need to display count and the count can change based on some filters applied (for e.g. price < 20)

What is the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

How big is your tree? Thousands or millions of elements? If the number of nodes is < 1000, performance is not an issue.

And most of the time, the number will be <10 since with AJAX, you can push each branch of the tree individually, so only the largest branch counts - somewhat. Say the largest branch is 1000 but the average branch has 10 nodes. In this case, you can ignore performance.

What you should do: Select an appropriate JavaScript framework to build the tree for you. Don't try this yourself. There are subtle browser bugs and differences that will drive you insane. Instead, try something like the [jQuery Treeview plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My tree will probably be in the tune of thousands and definitely not millions. To be specific its an assortment tree so 3 - 4 level of branches and asume 4th level is the leaf, the leaf itself would contain articles. About 1000 articles per leaf. Lets say an overall of 20K articles

Comment: I'm puzzled: How can a leaf contain something? A leaf can't be expanded, so it shouldn't matter how many articles it contains.

Comment: Sorry , may be wrong terminology of calling it the leaf, it simply is the level just above the last level. But coming to the actual solution itself, if i understand right, then you say it must be possible to publish the data to client on request from an AJAX call.  For e.g. when a branch is expanded,make an AJAX call and get the list of sub branches from the data structure i have...

Comment: Yes. But I'm worried about the 1000 leaf nodes (= articles). No human is able to handle such a huge amount of data; at 14px/line, that 14'000 pixels high. You should consider a different way to display them. The usual approach is paging or to display those in a table as main content (so the tree just gets you there and the articles are presented in the main area).

Comment: oops... again i think am not making myself clear. Indeed its like what you have said. We only have tree with branches on the left menu and on the right in a nice main content area we have the articles. My biggest worry is a feature i must support in which: the tree branches should be disabled/hidden if there are no articles in it. And the articles can change based on user actions(filter,search etc). So my initial tree construction is no problem,now if the usr applies a filter first i need to get the articles, then find the parent branches in which these articles are linked to..[cont]

Comment: based on my changed articles list on main content,i must refresh the tree. Do you think a plain push to thru AJAX would work. Am concerned on the performance, a few secs is ok, but a customer waiting for more than thatfor the tree to appear i guess is a problem. What am not able to zero in on is a stratergy to have a tree that is easy to build and refresh, regardless of its JSON / AJAX / Jquery...Any direction is much appreciated

Comment: There might be a more simple solution: If you can map the filter to CSS classes, you can simply say "hide anything with class `foo`"

Comment: Thanks for answering in detail..;will try it out, my plan was to do something similar to what you have mentioned for the filters. I think at the moment am too worried about performance issues that might occur, would be best to try it out i guess.. At this moment this solution is the best approach i could settle down for